# Get Access Token Without Login | Facebook`

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I am creating a web app and I need to make a call like this one:

`https://graph.facebook.com/639339682906611?access_token={my_access_token_here}`

When I obtain an access_token through the Graph API Explorer, it works fine. But after a while (some days I think) the token expires and I have to go to manually go to the Graph API Explorer again to renew it.

The web app requires no login for the users.

Is there a way to update my access_token automatically?
If not, is there a way to make my access_token last longer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is no way. You can only extend User or Page Tokens. Extended User Tokens are valid for 60 days, Extended Page Tokens are valid forever.

You can also try using an App Token, it is just a combination of App ID and App Secret. It is the only Token you don´t need authorization for: `access_token=app_id|app_secret`

More information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: The token that I use now is a user_token. My user's token. And by that I mean the user_token generated from my own profile on FB. Can I update this without FB login?

Comment: 'You can also try using an App Token, it is just a combination of App ID and App Secret. It is the only Token you don´t need authorization for.'

This works. Thank you.

Comment: For reference, this is the sample of code to use the App ID + App Secret technique: `https://graph.facebook.com/endpoint?key=value&amp;access_token=app_id|app_secret`

Comment: you can´t update user tokens without user interaction. that would make the whole point of short living tokens pointless. but if it works with an app token, just use that one. be aware that tokens need to be kept serect, only use the app token server side.

Comment: @padawanTony : https://graph.facebook.com/endpoint?key=value&amp;access_token=app_id|app_secret throws a '(#803) Cannot query users by their username (endpoint) error". What gives?

Comment: did you just try this with "endpoint"? that was just an example, of course you need to replace it with an actual endpoint ;)